# How to get each individual digit of a given number in Basic?

Tags: modulo, basic

I have one program downloaded from internet and need to get each digit printed out from a three digit number. For example:

Input: `123`

Expected Output:

```
1

2

3
```

I have `598`

Need to Get:

```
5
9
8
```

I try using this formula but the problem is when number is with decimal function failed:

```
FIRST_DIGIT  = (number mod 1000) / 100
SECOND_DIGIT = (number mod 100) / 10
THIRD_DIGIT  = (number mod 10)
```

Where number is the above example so here is calulation:

FIRST_DIGIT = (598 mod 1000) / 100 = 5,98 <== FAILED...i need to get 5 but my program shows 0 because i have decimal point

SECOND_DIGIT = (598 mod 100) / 10 = 9,8 <== FAILED...i need to get 9 but my program shows 0 because i have decimal point

THIRD_DIGIT = (598 mod 10) = 8 <== CORRECT...i get from program output number 8 and this digit is correct.

So my question is is there sample or more efficient code that get each digit from number without decimal point? I don't want to use round to round nearest number because sometime it fill failed if number is larger that .5.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do any fancy integer calculations as long as you pull it apart from a string:

```
INPUT X
X$ = STR$(X)
FOR Z = 1 TO LEN(X$)
    PRINT MID$(X$, Z, 1)
NEXT
```

Then, for example, you could act upon each string element:

```
INPUT X
X$ = STR$(X)
FOR Z = 1 TO LEN(X$)
    Q = VAL(MID$(X$, Z, 1))
    N = N + 1
    PRINT "Digit"; N; " equals"; Q
NEXT
```

Additionally, you could tear apart the string character by character:

```
INPUT X
X$ = STR$(X)
FOR Z = 1 TO LEN(X$)
    SELECT CASE MID$(X$, Z, 1)
        CASE " ", ".", "+", "-", "E", "D"
            ' special char
        CASE ELSE
            Q = VAL(MID$(X$, Z, 1))
            N = N + 1
            PRINT "Digit"; N; " equals"; Q
    END SELECT
NEXT
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use integer division (\) instead of floating point division (/).

If you replace each one of your examples with the backslash (\) instead of forward slash (/) they will return integer values.

```
FIRST_DIGIT  = (598 mod 1000) \ 100 = 5
SECOND_DIGIT = (598 mod 100) \ 10 = 9
THIRD_DIGIT  = (598 mod 10) = 8
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in Basic but looks like you have to convert floating point number to Integer. A quick google search told me that you have to use `Int(floating_point_number)` to convert float to integer.
So

   `Int((number mod 100)/ 10)`

should probably the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

And, finally, all string elements could be parsed:

```
INPUT X
X$ = STR$(X)
PRINT X$
FOR Z = 1 TO LEN(X$)
    SELECT CASE MID$(X$, Z, 1)
        CASE " "
            ' nul
        CASE "E", "D"
            Exponent = -1
        CASE "."
            Decimal = -1
        CASE "+"
            UnaryPlus = -1
        CASE "-"
            UnaryNegative = -1
        CASE ELSE
            Q = VAL(MID$(X$, Z, 1))
            N = N + 1
            PRINT "Digit"; N; " equals"; Q
    END SELECT
NEXT
IF Exponent THEN PRINT "There was an exponent."
IF Decimal THEN PRINT "There was a decimal."
IF UnaryPlus THEN PRINT "There was a plus sign."
IF UnaryNegative THEN PRINT "There was a negative sign."
```